# Технически правильная кроссплатформенная организация хранения пользовательских файлов в Java-приложениях

Tags: java, spring, кроссплатформенность

Как Вы знаете, в Windows файлы пользователя для большинства приложений хранятся в AppData/Roaming. У меня почти не опыта работы с MacOS и Linux, но думаю, там есть аналогичные папки.

Это относится не только к разработке Java-приложений, но полагаю, что как только мы запускаем приложение, первым делом оно должно проверять AppData/Roaming на наличие там своей подпапки и если её нет - создавать её.

Вопрос такой: есть ли что-нибудь получше, чем приведённый ниже алгоритм?

1. Узнаём ОС
2. Получаем в зависимости от ОС путь к папке пользовательскими настройками (AppData/Roaming в случае Windows)
3. Проверяем, если ли подпапка конкретно того приложения которое мы разрабатываем. Если есть - проверяем, есть ли права доступа к ней. Если нет - создаём.
4. Работаем с файлами подпапки.

Может быть, есть какая-нибудь подходящая библиотека от Spring?

Comment: Есть библиотека, но внутри там такая же логика https://github.com/harawata/appdirs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В моем случае приложение пишет в подпапку `Tomcat aplication server` поскольку оно одно. Алгоритм аналогичен вашему.

```
private static final String NIX_ROOT_FOLDER = "/opt/tomcat";
private static final String WIN_ROOT_FOLDER = "C:\\Users\\%username%\\AppData\\Roaming\\tomcat";
private static final String OS_NAME = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

public static final String ROOT_FOLDER = OS_NAME.contains("win") ? WIN_ROOT_FOLDER : NIX_ROOT_FOLDER;
```

---

Ничего плохого в таком алгоритме не вижу.

В общем случае имеет смысл писать в одну из следующих папок:

- В папку приложения (только до передеплоя)
- В папку пользователя
- В папку сервера приложений

Если планируется дальнейшая обработка этих файлов в других приложениях, то:

- В какую-либо выделенную папку на локальной машине
- В сетевую папку

---

`Spring`, на сколько я знаю дает только обертку для стандартных джавовских алгоритмов работы с файлами..

Comment: В общем случае веб приложение не должно писать в папку, принадлежащую контейнеру сервлетов.

Comment: Во-первых это сложно поддерживать при масштабировании на несколько контейнеров,  во вторых таким образом вы можете повлиять на целостность других приложений в этом контейнере. В третьих, при правильной организации установки по, томкат это один пакет а ваше приложение - другой, с вашим сценарием будет намного сложнее создать корректные скрипты для инсталляции деинсталляции. Это навскидку, то с чем реально сталкивался...

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Расскажу про мой тяжелый случай...

Искренне надеюсь что это вам никогда не пригодится

По специфике работы приходится иметь дело с МСВС 5 (мобильная система вооруженных сил), это такой RedHat linux на ядре 2.6, в ней помимо всего прочего реализована [мандатное управление доступом](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE).

Так вот, в таком окружении директория, в которую приложению позволено записывать файлы определяется именем пользователя, от которого запущен процесс и текущим уровнем доступа (особой важности/сов. секретно/секретно/не секретно), соответственно выглядит это примерно так:

```
/home/%username%/.tmp/0-0/ не секретно 
/home/%username%/.tmp/1-0/ секретно
/home/%username%/.tmp/2-0/ сов. секретно
/home/%username%/.tmp/3-0/ особой важности
```

Хорошим тоном в данном случае считается что приложение, никуда кроме как в папку пользователя не пишет, однако это возможно.

А для того чтобы получить уровень доступа в Java естественно никаких средств нет, и тут у вас либо JNI либо JNA или Runtime.exec(), при помощи которых нужно выяснить метку секретности процесса

Отвечая на Ваш вопрос:
по сути это ваш алгоритм, только с перламутровыми пуговицами...

**ADD**: так как топикстартер принял ответ, который может ввести людей а заблуждение, добавлю в свой ответ

В общем случае веб приложение не должно писать в папку, принадлежащую контейнеру сервлетов.
Во-первых это сложно поддерживать при масштабировании на несколько контейнеров, во вторых таким образом вы можете повлиять на целостность других приложений в этом контейнере. В третьих, при правильной организации установки по, томкат это один пакет а ваше приложение - другой, с вашим сценарием будет намного сложнее создать корректные скрипты для инсталляции деинсталляции. Это навскидку, то с чем реально сталкивался...

Comment: Господа минусующие, пишите комментарии с чем вы не согласны